# Indexer does not find printf/exit/fprintf (Eclipse + Qt + MinGW integration regarding stuff in stdio.h / stdlib.h / etc.)

Tags: eclipse, qt, mingw, indexer

I have a Qt Project and Eclipse started with the Qt Eclipse integration program. 
I am using the newest version of Qt (4.3.4), Eclipse and MinGW.

My problem is, that the Eclipse Indexer does not find stuff like `printf()`/`fprintf()`/`exit()`! The code compiles fine and the program runs normally!

e.g:

```
static void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
switch(event) {
/* left button down */
case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    MousePointerPosition = cvPoint(x,y);
    leftClicks = 1;
    break;

    /* right button down */
case CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
    fprintf(stdout, "Right button down (%d, %d).\n", x, y);
    break;

    /* mouse move */
case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    break;
}
}
```

I included a screenshot of the directories and files I included (note: I used Qt 4.7.3 in the screenshot, shouldn't make a difference)!

Any suggestions?

Here's a link to the screenshot (I am a new user..):
[screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/608132/capture.png)